# Outlook email template Padding/margin minus not working

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, margin

By minus i mean margin/padding:-#px

I have an image which I have put as a div background. Now I need to put three bottoms on the image. SIMPLE SAID : i need three bottoms on the image...in a browser i do it in a matter of seconds but  I've found no way how to do it in outlook. My last attempts where to wrap the divs in table and giving parameters to the table itself still not working.

A simple example of what I need to get in an email template.
[image]

That's what I receive in output no matter what manipulation I do
[image]

My first and cleanest code were simple as the idea itself (just to put three bottoms on an image) but obsolute not working padding not working margin not working in outlook:

```html
    <body>
      <div class="MainImage" align="right">
        <img class="topimage" style="width:600px;height:900px;position:absolute;" src="Files/Meuhedet_eMailTemplate.png" alt="">
        <a href=""> <img class="topimage" style="width:150px;height:25px;position:absolute;margin-top:750px;margin-left:42px;" src="Files/Meuhedet_buy.png" alt=""> </a>
        <a href=""> <img class="topimage" style="width:150px;height:25px;position:absolute;margin-top:750px;margin-left:230px;" src="Files/Meuhedet_Tor.png" alt=""> </a>
        <a href=""> <img class="topimage" style="width:150px;height:25px;position:absolute;margin-top:750px;margin-left:415px;" src="Files/Meuhedet_Inf.png" alt=""> </a>
        <a href=""> <img class="topimage" style="width:140px;height:14px;position:absolute;margin-top:857px;margin-left:435px;" src="Files/Meuhedet_Website.png" alt=""> </a>
        <a href=""> <img class="topimage" style="width:60px;height:12px;position:absolute;margin-top:860px;margin-left:355px;" src="Files/Meuhedet_Tel.png" alt=""> </a>
      </div>
    </body>
```

This is how my code looks now...still no results
[image]
Eventually I got to something very complicated and lots of garbage code but nothing worked including wrapping img in grid table tr td and still am not able to use `Margin-top: #px`.

Comment: What does "minus" mean in your title? I think you may have meant something else. Menus? Maybe it should read "... on menu items...".

Comment: What is a screenshot of the output you are expecting?